# How can I optimally filter a view from a stored procedure that accepts lots of nullable parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

**The content of this question is long so please bear with me.**

I am looking for a way to filter a view from a stored procedure where the stored procedure has a bunch of parameters that can be nullable.

Here are the options I've identified for doing this, along with any pros and cons I can see for them:

### Option 1: Delete From A Temp Table

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetView1Filtered
    @ForeignKeyID1   int = null,
    @ForeignKeyID2   int = null,
    @ForeignKeyID3   int = null,
    @ForeignKeyID4   int = null,
    @WildcardString1 varchar(128) = null,
    @WildcardString2 varchar(128) = null,
    @WildcardString3 varchar(128) = null,
    @DateRange1Start date         = null,
    @DateRange1End   date         = null
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    INTO #TempView1
    FROM View1

    IF @ForeignKeyID1 IS NOT NULL
        DELETE #TempView1 
        WHERE ForeignKeyID1 <> @ForeignKeyID1

    IF @ForeignKeyID2 IS NOT NULL
        DELETE #TempView1 
        WHERE ForeignKeyID2 <> @ForeignKeyID2

    -- ...

    IF @WildcardString1 IS NOT NULL
        DELETE #TempView1 
        WHERE NOT WildcardString1 LIKE '%' + @WildcardString1 + '%'

    -- ...

END
```

> Pros of **Option 1**
>
> - Easy maintainability, easy to read, easy to modify.
> - Deletes are fast and they are only run as needed.
> - Execution plan can be cached and optimized.
> - Can handle large amount of parameters.
>
> Cons of **Option 1**
>
> - Performance is dependent upon the initial select of the view.
> - Unnecessary overhead to select rows that are going to be deleted.

---

### Option 2: Building Dynamic SQL

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetView1Filtered
    @ForeignKeyID1   int = null,
    @ForeignKeyID2   int = null,
    @ForeignKeyID3   int = null,
    @ForeignKeyID4   int = null,
    @WildcardString1 varchar(128) = null,
    @WildcardString2 varchar(128) = null,
    @WildcardString3 varchar(128) = null,
    @DateRange1Start date         = null,
    @DateRange1End   date         = null
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SqlStatement VARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @ParamDefinition VARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @SqlStatement = 'SELECT * FROM View1'

    IF @ForeignKeyID1 IS NOT NULL
        SET @SqlStatement = 
            @SqlStatement + ' AND ForeignKeyID1 = @ForeignKeyID1';

    IF @ForeignKeyID2 IS NOT NULL
        SET @SqlStatement = 
            @SqlStatement + ' AND ForeignKeyID2 = @ForeignKeyID2';

    -- ...

    IF @WildcardString1 IS NOT NULL
        SET @SqlStatement = 
            @SqlStatement + ' AND WildcardString1 LIKE ''%'' + 
                                 @WildcardString1 + ''%''';

    -- ...

    SET @ParamDefinition = '@ForeignKeyID1   int,
                            @ForeignKeyID2   int,
                            @ForeignKeyID3   int,
                            @ForeignKeyID4   int,
                            @WildcardString1 varchar(128),
                            @WildcardString2 varchar(128),
                            @WildcardString3 varchar(128),
                            @DateRange1Start date,       
                            @DateRange1End   date'       

    EXECUTE sp_Executesql   @SqlStatement, 
                            @ParamDefinition, 
                            @ForeignKeyID1,
                            @ForeignKeyID2,     
                            @ForeignKeyID3, 
                            @ForeignKeyID4, 
                            @WildcardString1,
                            @WildcardString2,
                            @WildcardString3,
                            @DateRange1Start,
                            @DateRange1End  
END
```

> Pros of **Option 2**
>
> - Query is run with the exact parameters needed to filter the view
> - Maintainability is not too bad, structure is similar to option 1 but with a bit more work.
> - Can handle large amount of parameters.
>
> Cons of **Option 2**
>
> - No optimization of the query execution plan.
> - Might be unwarranted but I've seen major performance degradation with this on views that are slightly complex.
> - *Possible bias:* This approach just doesn't feel like it's too good in the long run.

---

### Option 3: Permutations Of SQL Parameters

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetView1Filtered
    @ForeignKeyID1   int = null,
    @ForeignKeyID2   int = null,
    @ForeignKeyID3   int = null,
    @ForeignKeyID4   int = null,
    @WildcardString1 varchar(128) = null,
    @WildcardString2 varchar(128) = null,
    @WildcardString3 varchar(128) = null,
    @DateRange1Start date         = null,
    @DateRange1End   date         = null
AS
BEGIN
    IF @ForeignKeyID1   IS NOT NULL AND
       @ForeignKeyID2   IS NULL     AND
       @ForeignKeyID3   IS NULL     AND
       @ForeignKeyID4   IS NULL     AND
       @WildcardString1 IS NULL     AND
       @WildcardString2 IS NULL     AND
       @WildcardString3 IS NULL     AND
       @DateRange1Start IS NULL     AND
       @DateRange1End   IS NULL

       BEGIN
           SELECT *
           FROM View1
           WHERE ForeignKeyID1 = @ForeignKeyID1
       END
    ELSE IF @ForeignKeyID1   IS NOT NULL AND
            @ForeignKeyID2   IS NOT NULL AND
            @ForeignKeyID3   IS NULL     AND
            @ForeignKeyID4   IS NULL     AND
            @WildcardString1 IS NULL     AND
            @WildcardString2 IS NULL     AND
            @WildcardString3 IS NULL     AND
            @DateRange1Start IS NULL     AND
            @DateRange1End   IS NULL

       BEGIN
           SELECT *
           FROM View1
           WHERE ForeignKeyID1 = @ForeignKeyID1 AND 
                 ForeignKeyID2 = @ForeignKeyID2 
       END

    -- ...

END
```

> Pros of **Option 3**
>
> - Execution plan optimization.
> - No unnecessary overhead of row selection.
>
> Cons of **Option 3**
>
> - Absolutely a nightmare to maintain.
> - Can only work for a very low number of parameters, otherwise the permutations are too high.

---

### Option 4: ID Selection Into Temp Table

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetView1Filtered
    @ForeignKeyID1   int = null,
    @ForeignKeyID2   int = null,
    @ForeignKeyID3   int = null,
    @ForeignKeyID4   int = null,
    @WildcardString1 varchar(128) = null,
    @WildcardString2 varchar(128) = null,
    @WildcardString3 varchar(128) = null,
    @DateRange1Start date         = null,
    @DateRange1End   date         = null
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #Temp
    (
        PrimaryKeyID int NOT NULL
    );

    IF @ForeignKeyID1 IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Temp (PrimaryKeyID)
                SELECT PrimaryKeyID
                FROM View1
                WHERE ForeignKeyID1 = @ForeignKeyID1
        END

    IF @ForeignKeyID2 IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Temp (PrimaryKeyID)
                SELECT PrimaryKeyID
                FROM View1
                WHERE ForeignKeyID2 = @ForeignKeyID2
        END

    -- ...

    SELECT *
    FROM View1
        INNER JOIN (SELECT PrimaryKeyID 
                    FROM #Temp 
                    GROUP BY PrimaryKeyID) t ON 
            t.PrimaryKeyID = View1.PrimaryKeyID

    DROP TABLE #Temp

END
```

> Pros of **Option 4**
>
> - Maintainability is not too bad.
> - Can handle large amount of parameters.
> - Execution plan can be cached and optimized.
>
> Cons of **Option 4**
>
> - Performance is degraded because inserts are slow.
> - As-needed inserts can still result in large performance degradation.

---

### Option 5: Case Statements

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetView1Filtered
    @ForeignKeyID1   int = null,
    @ForeignKeyID2   int = null,
    @ForeignKeyID3   int = null,
    @ForeignKeyID4   int = null,
    @WildcardString1 varchar(128) = null,
    @WildcardString2 varchar(128) = null,
    @WildcardString3 varchar(128) = null,
    @DateRange1Start date         = null,
    @DateRange1End   date         = null
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM View1
    WHERE
        (CASE WHEN @ForeignKeyID1 IS NULL 
         THEN 1 ELSE 
            CASE WHEN ForeignKeyID1 = @ForeignKeyID1 
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END = 1) AND
        (CASE WHEN @ForeignKeyID2 IS NULL 
         THEN 1 ELSE 
            CASE WHEN ForeignKeyID2 = @ForeignKeyID2 
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END = 1) AND
        (CASE WHEN @WildcardString1 IS NULL 
         THEN 1 ELSE 
            CASE WHEN WildcardString1 LIKE '%' + @WildcardString1 + '%' 
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END END = 1)

    -- ...

END
```

> Pros of **Option 5**
>
> - Maintainability is not too bad.
> - Can technically handle a bunch of parameters.
> - Only one select statement and processing only goes to getting the rows needed.
> - Execution plan can be cached and optimized.
>
> Cons of **Option 5**
>
> - I haven't tested this one extensively but I don't think the performance will be very good. I don't think the SQL engine will like
>     processing a ton of case statements for each row.

---

Those are the options I've identified. I don't know how accurate my pros and cons are for them, feel free to correct me. Anyway, I'm hoping I can get some insight into how this is best achieved. I often run into situations where this type of filtering is necessary and I'd like to have a good solution to tackle it.

Ideally, I'd like the solution to be able to handle slower views that have lots of rows.

Comment: `No optimization of the query execution plan.` What? SQL Server optimizes at the statement level, and it can optimize statements from dynamic SQL just fine. The problem you will find is not query plan optimization, but plan cache bloat. You can avoid this to some degree by using the server-wide setting `Optimize for ad hoc workloads` - this prevents a full plan from occupying its true space in the cache until it's been requested twice.

Comment: +1 for a very well presented question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're over-complicating this.

A standard way to deal with this type of situation is:

```
SELECT
  <columns>
FROM
  MyView
WHERE
  (@Param1 IS NULL OR ColA = @Param1)
  AND (@Param2 IS NULL OR ColB = @Param2)
...
```

There's no need for complicated logic here involving deleting from temporary result sets.

Comment: +1, although the dynamic SQL solution might get better plans if the values of the parameters tend to change

Comment: @JNK The parameters I used were pretty simple, but what if I have say 5-10 parameters that are xml with lists of ids?

Comment: Then you use the same logic. If you need to you can put them into temp tables to join on as well.

Comment: @test why would you pass lists IDs in XML? *shudder* You should use table-valued parameters.

Comment: Constructive Criticism: On a large table with different combinations of parameters the query performance with this method will go tits up :)

Comment: @M.Ali actually it won't unless you have some really edge-case type uses like the aformentioned XML.

Comment: In my recent experience with similar situation, using your proposed method did have a great impact on the performance, but when I changed the code to what I have suggested in my answer it did improve the performance by almost two folds. Further investigation revealed sql server doesnt do short-circuiting in where clause, even if one condition is true in an `OR` it might go ahead and check the other condition anyway. And also I think parameter sniffing was another factor which made the query performance suffer.

Comment: @M.Ali If you are just checking for `NULL` or not in a variable, that's a constant scan and both conditions will almost never be checked. If you're comparing two OPERATIONS then that may have an impact, but in this scenario it should be trivial for the engine to check the param for NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest and an efficient way of dealing with this kind of situation, will be to build the query string and execute. How you build the query string? there are many way of doing that I find the following simplest and easiest:

Your Option two is the closest match to my proposed method. But to avoid the complexity of which will be the 1st parameter and where you have to use `AND` and where you shouldnt this can be avoided simply by adding a simple where condition which will always evaluate to true like I have used `WHERE 1 = 1`, After this point any more conditions is WHERE clause will have to have an `AND` in the beginning.

Also instead of using IF statements to check whether a variable is NULL or Not you can put all this together by just simply using CASE statement which makes it a bit simpler to read.

Please see below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetView1Filtered
@ForeignKeyID1   int = null,
@ForeignKeyID2   int = null,
@ForeignKeyID3   int = null,
@ForeignKeyID4   int = null,
@WildcardString1 varchar(128) = null,
@WildcardString2 varchar(128) = null,
@WildcardString3 varchar(128) = null,
@DateRange1Start date         = null,
@DateRange1End   date         = null
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

  SET @Sql = N' SELECT * FROM View WHERE 1 = 1'
            + CASE WHEN @ForeignKeyID1 IS NOT NULL 
                 THEN N' AND ForeignKeyID1 <> @ForeignKeyID1 ' ELSE N' ' END

            + CASE WHEN @ForeignKeyID2 IS NOT NULL 
                 THEN N' AND ForeignKeyID2 <> @ForeignKeyID2 ' ELSE N' ' END

            + CASE WHEN @ForeignKeyID3 IS NOT NULL 
                 THEN N' AND ForeignKeyID3 <> @ForeignKeyID3 ' ELSE N' ' END

            + CASE WHEN @ForeignKeyID4 IS NOT NULL 
                 THEN N' AND ForeignKeyID4 <> @ForeignKeyID4 ' ELSE N' ' END

            + CASE WHEN @ForeignKeyID1 IS NOT NULL 
                 THEN N' AND ForeignKeyID1 <> @ForeignKeyID1 ' ELSE N' ' END

             ...........

  EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
                      ,N'@ForeignKeyID1   int
                        @ForeignKeyID2   int,
                        @ForeignKeyID3   int,
                        @ForeignKeyID4   int,
                        @WildcardString1 varchar(128),
                        @WildcardString2 varchar(128),
                        @WildcardString3 varchar(128),
                        @DateRange1Start date        ,
                        @DateRange1End   date        '
                        ,@ForeignKeyID1, @ForeignKeyID2, @ForeignKeyID3
                        ,........
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Plain TSQL with option recompile should be included in this list as well. It isn't right for every situation, but it's where I start from.

```
WHERE
   (@Param1 IS NULL OR @Param1 = col1)
   AND (@Param2 IS NULL OR @Param2 = col2)
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

Recompiling will allow for an optimized query based on the specific parameters. It's plain sql, so it's easier to read and maintain. It doesn't get cached, so there isn't memory bloat.

The drawback is the cpu cost of recompilation each time, on complex queries this can become significant.

Erland Sommarskog did a writeup of the different approaches to this problem that's worth reviewing. (Not that I've seen anything of his that isn't.) [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html).